# Нужно ли обособление? 3

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, синтаксис

***Больше поликлиник я ненавижу только то, когда меня, с развязанными шнурками, догоняет отец.***
(Подразумевается, что у меня развязаны шнурки.)

Нужно ли обособлять "с развязанными шнурками"?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что  это сочетание обособляется, так как относится к личному местоимению.

У Розенталя есть правило: Несогласованные определения, выраженные формами косвенных падежей существительных, обособляются:3) если относятся к личному местоимению:

Я удивляюсь, что вы, с вашей добротой, не чувствуете этого (Л. Т.); …Сегодня она, в новом голубом капоте, была особенно молода (М. Г.);

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, это предложение неудачно составлено. В усеченном предложении "Ненавижу то, когда меня догоняет отец" слово "то" - лишнее. И вообще стилистически неудачно сравнение предмета "поликлиники" с ситуацией "меня догоняет отец". Я бы предложил, например, выразить эту мысль  так:

**Я ненавижу, когда меня приводят в поликлинику, но еще больше ненавижу, когда меня, с развязанными шнурками, догоняет отец.**

Согласен с @Arina: несогласованное определение "с развязанными шнурками" должно обособляться.